# anaconda create environment didn't work by using conda create -n envirement_name

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to create a python environment using anaconda.

The create script did not seem to work. Is there any way to troubleshoot？

```
(base) D:\>conda create -n mxnet python=3.6

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

(base) D:\>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  D:\Anaconda3
feathernets              D:\Anaconda3\envs\feathernets
```

OS: windows10 x86-64

conda version : 4.8.1

conda-build version : 3.18.9